# need keyboard shortcut to change css code, inline to branched in ubuntu sublime text3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, ubuntu-14.04

What is the keyboard-shortcut in **sublime text3** (on **ubuntu**) change css from inline to branched ( I don't know what it called exactly ) and back

### inline

```
body { background-color: #112D2A; font-size: 12px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; }
```

I want to change above inline way css into branched way css

### branched

```
body { 
      background-color: #112D2A;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
}
```

#### what I have tried

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+M</kbd> select the content within `{`

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Space</kbd> select the content within `{` block by block

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+J</kbd> doesnt' work

and if it does'n exist then how do we add in key binding, what will be argument?

Comment: Have you checked out the packages available? If you use sass, you might wanna check out sass beautify plugin by Bad Syntax. It lets you beautify sass code. After quickly surfing I saw this, does https://github.com/fitnr/SublimeCSSTidy work for you?

Comment: I am not using sass. and it's not about sass

Answer (score 1):

I used Sublime 3 only once to look for new features and as far as I know there'S no builtin one-click feature.

Beside writing your own plugin you might do this how I would do this by using the builtin multi-select/multi-caret feature:

### Oneline to multiline

Line:

> body { background-color: #112D2A; font-size: 12px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; }

1. Select the first semicolon (<kbd>;</kbd> means it's selected):

> body { background-color: #112D2A<kbd>;</kbd> font-size: 12px; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; }

2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> until you've selected all `;`:

> body { background-color: #112D2A<kbd>;</kbd> font-size: 12px<kbd>;</kbd> margin: 0<kbd>;</kbd> padding: 0<kbd>;</kbd> font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif<kbd>;</kbd> }

3. Enter `;` to get rid of the selections and to collapse the selection into multiple cursors after the semicolons (the `|` indicates the cursor):

> body { background-color: #112D2A;| font-size: 12px;| margin: 0;| padding: 0;| font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;| }

4. Press <kbd>RETURN</kbd> to insert newlines:

> body { background-color: #112D2A;
>   
> | font-size: 12px;
>   
> | margin: 0;
>   
> | padding: 0;
>   
> | font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
>   
> | }

5. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to leave the multi select/caret mode
6. Correct the break after the first curly brace.

Et voila.

After step 3. you might add another caret after the first curly brace by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking at that place to skip step 6.

### Multiline to oneline

Lines:

> body { 
>   
>    background-color: #112D2A;
>   
>    font-size: 12px;
>   
>    margin: 0;
>   
>    padding: 0;
>   
>    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
>   
> }

1. Add extra tab / space befor closing curly brace (see step 4)

> body { 
>   
>    background-color: #112D2A;
>   
>    font-size: 12px;
>   
>    margin: 0;
>   
>    padding: 0;
>   
>    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
>   
>    }

2. Place the cursor in the first column of the second line and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> till the last line:

> body { 
>   
> |   background-color: #112D2A;
>   
> |   font-size: 12px;
>   
> |   margin: 0;
>   
> |   padding: 0;
>   
> |   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
>   
> |}

3. Press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

> body { background-color: #112D2A;| font-size: 12px;| margin: 0;| padding: 0;| font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;| }

4. Press <kbd>DEL</kbd> to delete the superflous space chars / tabs
5. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to cancle the selection

Et voila.

Comment: isn't it a long procedure? Thank you for the valuable effort but I was asking keyboard-shortcut.:\
and my OP was to 'also switch back' to inline?

Comment: As I said, there's probably no buildin shortcut since Sublime is not only made for CSS or C - different languages/scripts/markups, different needs. Either some manual steps or a plugin. I'll add how to do the reversal. ;)